# What to do if you said the morning Brachot out of order?

Tags: blessing, shacharis-morning-prayer

Halachipedia [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birchot_HaShachar#Order_of_Brachot) states that the Shulchan Orach and Mishneh Berurah write that if one accidentally says Zokef Kefufim before Matir Assurim, it might not be best to go back and say Matir Assurim. While this seems clear, I am curious on the process if one says the other morning brachot our of order; i.e., if one said Shelo Asani Isha before Shelo Asani Goy, or if one said Matir Assurim before Malbish Arumim. Are there any sources on that?

Comment: Isn't this addressed in the same subsection you linked to?

Comment: Note the majority of pre-shulchan-aruch siddurim have Mattir Asurim **after** Zokef Kefufim, so many strongly question that ruling you bring (which is likely based on a bad girsa in some geonim)

Comment: @dov chabad also has a different order

Comment: @dov in halachipedia he brings your question next to the din you quoted but does not bring the MB which I gave as the answer. I dont know how reliable he is to argue with the MB

Answer (score 3):

> (טז) **עכו"ם** — ואם בירך מתחלה שלא עשני אשה י"א דשוב לא יוכל לברך שלא עשני עכו"ם ושלא עשני עבד כי אשה עדיפה משתיהן וממילא נכלל ההודאה כי בכלל מאתים מנה. וכן אם בירך שלא ע"ע לא יוכל לברך שלא עשני גוי כי עבד עדיף מגוי דחייב בקצת מצות. אבל הרבה אחרונים חולקין בכל זה וכן הסכים הא"ר ודה"ח דיוכל לברך ‏

The [MB](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%95) says it is a machlokes (an arguement) if once you have not a 'woman' you can still say not a 'servant' or 'nonjew'. But he ends by saying you can. Not like the sefer brought in the question who says you cant without mentioning the MB at all which is unusual today. One does not have to agree but one should mention him.